# Php socket headers from client

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I have a socket server that handles connections. Here I have a `doHandshake` method.

```
function doHandshake($received_header, $client_socket_resource, $host_name, $port) {
    var_dump($received_header);
    // do stuf here with header
}
```

When I want to connect from **javascript client**, It works fine, and prints all headers such as `Sec-WebSocket-Key`. This is how I use doHandShake method in socket server:

```
$header = socket_read($newSocket, 1024);
$chatHandler->doHandshake($header, $newSocket, HOST_NAME, PORT);
```

In the other hand I have a php client. When I connect from php client, header is a string that I send to server not a real header. Here is my client socket in php:

```
$host    = "127.0.0.1";
$port    = 8090;
$message = "Hello Server";
echo "Message To server :".$message;
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// connect to server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
// send string to server
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
// get server response

$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
// close socket
socket_close($socket);
```

Any idea how to send socket headers in php client??

**Note:** This is done automatically in **javascript client**.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript client (a browser?) is making an HTTP request with an `Upgrade` header to negotiate a WebSocket connection. It's not just connecting and sending `Hello Server`. If you want your PHP client to do something similar, you need to implement [the required protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). The Upgrade request and the WebSocket protocol are both non-trivial to implement, so it's hard to give a quick answer, but you can partially emulate what the browser is doing like this:

```
$message = "GET /ws HTTP/1.1\r\n" .
           "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
           "Origin: example.com\r\n" .
           "Sec-WebSocket-Key: blahblah\r\n" .
           "\r\n";
```

You would be *much* better off looking for a third-party WebSocket client implemented in PHP rather than trying to write your own.

Comment: Thanks. I have added that part manually, but then I get this error: `Warning: socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [10053]: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.`

I think I must use `socket` protocol instead of `WebSocket`.